# Other sources of light to bless Shabbat over

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting, lighting

In places were candles are unsafe or prohibited from use, could light emitting diodes with batteries substitute?  Closing the circuit would be regarded as work. But so is lighting a candle for any other purpose but the blessing.  Could an analogy of kindling a candle be applied to activating the substitute to honor shabbat only?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya eternalsquire. This question is very relevant, particularly in hospital, and other places with a formal prohibition to manipulate fire. Very good. Why want you to close circuit before Knissat Shabbat?

Comment: Hi eternalsquire, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36466/may-one-say-a-blessing-on-light-bulbs-for-shabbat

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36466? cc @mbloch

Comment: @msh210 I don't disagree and mentioned it in the comment above yours. One could argue this one is "special" because it is asking about LEDs and batteries specifically. Batteries makes it much more acceptable, LED is a good question. But it is very close to the other indeed

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can light shabbat "candles" using battery powered flashlights. Some rule you can even do so using electric lights (although others disagree).

Here is [one source](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1655)

> Hacham Ben Sion, in his work Or Le'sion (vol. 3, p. 189, and vol. 2,
>   18:13), writes that one does not fulfill the obligation of Shabbat
>   candles with electric lights because the "fuel" is not present at the
>   time of lighting. When a person lights a candle, all the wax or oil
>   needed to sustain the flame is already present. An electric lamp,
>   however, is sustained by the electric current that is constantly being
>   fed into the lamp. Since that current is not present at the time of
>   lighting, one cannot use such a light for this obligation. Hacham Ben
>   Sion contends that this would be analogous to an oil lamp that has
>   just several drops of oil, and into which one slowly pours oil drop by
>   drop. Clearly, one cannot recite the Beracha over lighting in such a
>   fashion, since the fuel needed to sustain the flame for the required
>   period is not already present. Likewise, according to Hacham Ben Sion,
>   one cannot fulfill the obligation of Shabbat candles with an electric
>   light.
>
> [...]
>
> **Of course, if we follow this rationale, we would allow using a battery-operated light for this Misva. As Hacham Ben Sion notes, in
>   the case of a battery-operated light all the power is already
>   contained in the mechanism, and it would therefore suffice for the
>   obligation of Shabbat candle lighting.**
>
> **Hacham Ovadia Yosef, in his work Yabia Omer (vol. 9), disagrees, and rules that in principle, one can, in fact, fulfill the obligation with
>   electric lights.** Since when all is said and done electric lights
>   have the effect of providing illumination, they suffice for this Misva
>   regardless of the fact that the source of power is not currently
>   present.
>
> This ruling has numerous ramifications. **For example, if a person
>   spends Shabbat in a hotel or hospital, where he is not permitted to
>   kindle a flame, he may turn on an electric light before Shabbat in
>   fulfillment of the obligation to light Shabbat candles.** (Rav Aharon
>   Kotler is likewise reported to have taken this position.)

and here from [Ohr](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/93/Q2/) (!)

> Most Poskim, therefore, say that you may use electric lights and even
>   recite the blessing over them, since they add to Shalom Bayit and Oneg
>   Shabbat the same way as candles.
>
> Some Poskim, however, differentiate between battery-powered lights,
>   such as flashlights, and those that run on electricity generated from
>   a power plant. **Battery-powered lights are all right** since they
>   contain 'fuel' - i.e., the battery - which is right there when you
>   light it. Regular lights, on the other hand, have no 'fuel'. Rather,
>   the electricity is 'piped' in from the outside; and furthermore, the
>   electricity doesn't really exist yet - it's being created every second
>   at the power plant. In a sense it's like lighting a wick with no oil.
>   It's known about Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, zatzal, that once when he was
>   in a hotel and unable to light candles, he 'lit' a flashlight and made
>   a blessing over it.
>
> Sources
>
> - The Radiance of Shabbos, Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen
> - Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchata 2:43, footnote 22

There is a question of what type of lightbulb qualifies, and whether a traditional incandescent lightbulb is required (because it is closest to fire) or whether fluorescent (and presumably LEDs) would suffice. In an [extensive review of sources](http://cslr.law.emory.edu/fileadmin/media/PDFs/Lectures/Broyde_Electrically_Produced_Fire.pdf) R Howard Jachter and R Michael Broyde conclude that fluorescent lights are permitted for shabbat candles in cases where candles are not possible, based on R Ovadia Yosef and R Neuwirth (same sources as above).

As always [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com) before using this in actual cases.

Comment: LEDS can generate plenty of heat and burn up if the voltage is too high. I know this as personal experience.  Further, according to thermodynamics, no energy system is 100% efficient.  There will always be waste heat.  Note also that heat is infrared light.